# use Fermat's little theorem to show there is no solution to an equation

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

Hi guys, I have two questions while reading the answer:

1. Why is $4$ the order of $x$ in $G$?
2. Why is $p-1$ the order of $G?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since $x^4 \equiv 1 \pmod p$, the order of $x$ must divide $4$ by LaGrange's Theorem. It is not $2$, since $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$ and $-1 \not \equiv 1 \pmod p$ since $p \neq 2$. It is also not $1$, since then we would have $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and again $1 \not \equiv -1 \pmod p$. Therefore the order of $x$ must be $4$.
2. The order of $G$ is $p - 1$ because $G$ is the group of elements in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ that have a multiplicative inverse $\mod p$. An element $m \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has a multiplicative inverse if and only if $\gcd(m,n) = 1$. Since $p$ is prime, every element nonzero $m \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, and so the order of $G$ is $p - 1$, i.e. the number of nonzero elements.

Comment: One more question, if a group G contains an element of order 2, can I say the group G must contain a subgroup of order 2?

Comment: Yes. More generally, if $p$ is a prime dividing the order of a group $G$, then Cauchy's theorem tells you that there is an element $x \in G$ of order $p$, hence the subgroup generated by $x$ is an order $p$ subgroup.

Comment: I get it! Thanks!